# If $A$ and $B$ are countable, then $A\times B$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> If $A$ and $B$ are countable, then $A\times B$ is countable.

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma 1*: $A$ is countable if and only if there exists a injective mapping $f:A \to \Bbb N$.

*Lemma 2*: $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable.

Since $A$ and $B$ are countable, there exist injections $j_A:A \to \Bbb N$ and $j_B:B \to \Bbb N$ by *Lemma 1*.

We define a mapping $j:A\times B \to \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ by $j(a,b)=(j_A(a),j_B(b))$. It's clear that $j$ is injective.

Since $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable by *Lemma 2*, there exists an injection $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ by *Lemma 1*.

Hence $f\circ j:A\times B \to \Bbb N$ in injective and hence $A\times B$ is countable by *Lemma 1*.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: "It's clear that $j$ is injective" is not enough, you still need a proof, but it is good apart from this

Comment: Do you know that a countable union of countable sets is countable?  That's another route.

Comment: @Randall I have just presented a proof for it at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914550/if-a-is-a-countable-set-and-each-a-in-a-is-countable-then-bigcup-a-in ^^

Comment: You have already solved a generalization of this problem here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914514/the-cartesian-product-of-a-finite-number-of-countable-sets-is-countable **Edit** Re: the comments below, my mistake!

Comment: @LeAnhDung  Great!  Then note that $A \times B = \bigcup_{a \in A} \{a\} \times B$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest he use this to prove the generalization

Comment: @MikeEarnest Actually no :) The theorem in this post is actually a lemma in the post you linked.

Comment: @Holo I just meant that. You are faster than me ^^

Comment: @LeAnhDung hah, nice(after sitting on my butt and being on the computer most of the day I learned to type fast :P)

Comment: @Randall your approach is much more elegant if we've already known some lemmas ^^

Comment: For some entertaining and informative reading on this subject I suggest "Stories About Sets" by Vilenkin.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWainfleet! Let me have a look at it.