# Given a set $A$ and $n$ many $f_i$-ary functions $F_i$, the closure of a countable set $B$ under all the $F_i$'s is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ be a finite sequence of natural numbers where $f_i>0$ for all $i\le n$.

Let $A$ be a set and $F_i$ be an $f_i-$array operation on $A$ for all $i\le n$.

$B\subseteq A$ is *closed* if and only if $F_i(a_1,\cdots,a_{f_i})\in B$ for all $i\le n$ and $a_1,\cdots,a_{f_i}\in B$ provided that $F_i(a_1,\cdots,a_{f_i})$ is defined.

The closure of $B$, to be denoted by $\overline B$, is defined by $$\overline B=\bigcap\{C\in\mathcal P(A)\mid B\subseteq C \text{ and }C \text{ is closed}\}$$

> If $B$ is countable, then $\overline B$ is countable

---

Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

---

**My attempt:**

**Lemma 1:** $\overline B=\bigcup\limits_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j$ where $(B_j\mid j\in\Bbb N)$ is defined recursively by $$B_0=B \text{ and } B_{j+1}=B_j\bigcup \bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_i[B_j^{f_i}]\bigg)$$ (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923800/find-the-closure-of-a-set-under-many-operations))

**Lemma 2:** Countable union of countable sets is countable (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914550/if-a-is-a-countable-set-and-each-a-in-a-is-countable-then-bigcup-a-in))

**Lemma 3:** The Cartesian product of a finite number of countable sets is countable (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914514/the-cartesian-product-of-a-finite-number-of-countable-sets-is-countable))

By **Lemma 1**, $\overline B=\bigcup\limits_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j$ where $(B_j\mid j\in\Bbb N)$ where $$B_0=B \text{ and } B_{j+1}=B_j\bigcup \bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_i[B_j^{f_i}]\bigg)$$

First, we prove that $B_j$ is countable for all $j\in\Bbb N$ by induction on $j$. Since $B_0=B$ and $B$ is countable, $B_0$ is countable. Assume $B_k$ is countable. Thus $B_k^{f_i}$ is countable for all $i\le n$ by **Lemma 3**. Hence $B_k\bigcup \bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_i[B_k^{f_i}]\bigg)$ is countable by **Lemma 2**. It follows that $B_{k+1}$ is countable. By principle of induction, $B_j$ is countable for all $j\in\Bbb N$. Hence $\overline B=\bigcup\limits_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j$ is countable by **Lemma 2**.

Comment: Closure under *what*? The title is misleading. The closure of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$, for example. The closure of the eventually $0$ sequences is $\ell^2$ or $\ell^1$ or $\ell^{42}$, depending on your space. Closure is as ubiquitous in mathematics as possible. Be more concrete about it. You have 150 letters in your title, use them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have defined *closure* in my post. I think it's almost possible to insert that definition into the title.

Comment: I think that you're underestimating how much you can insert in 150 characters. You want this to be helpful for future readers who might learn something from your proofs, right? Then make it easier for *everyone* to actually understand what is inside your post even before they open it.

Comment: @AsafKaragil  Please take this discussion to meta math.

Comment: @William: Not every discussion is for meta math. Please exercise judgement with that suggestion. Feel free to open discussions on meta if you think that it's more appropriate to have certain discussions there. (One caveat is that if it is *not* in fact more appropriate, your question there is likely to be closed and/or deleted.)