# Suppose that $f:A\to B$ where $A$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable. Then there exists $b \in B$ such that $f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Suppose that $f$ is a mapping from an uncountable set $A$ to a countable set $B$. Then there exists $b \in B$ such that $f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is uncountable.

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma:* Countable union of countable sets is countable. (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914550/if-a-is-a-countable-set-and-each-a-in-a-is-countable-then-bigcup-a-in))

Assume the contrary that $f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is countable for all $b \in B$. It's clear that $A=\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}f^{−1}[\{b\}]$. Moreover, $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is a countable union of countable sets. Then $A=\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is countable by *Lemma*. This clearly contradicts the fact that $A$ is uncountable. Hence there exists $b \in B$ such that $f^{−1}[\{b\}]$ is uncountable.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: Relax. It's fine.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos :) I'm really relaxed ^^